# Plotting a yearly average density map in ArcMap 10.8

Tags: arcmap, density, average

I have one million rows of lightning data that covers 5 years (2017-2021), and the data includes latitude, longitude, and current. I used the latitude and longitude to create yearly maps in ArcMap using the point density tool. I need to create a yearly average density map.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question to give an indication of what the output of Point Density looks like, and what an average should be calculated.

Comment: Thank you for putting my inquiry in the correct sequence, @Vince.
As previously stated, I was able to make yearly maps in ArcMap by employing the point density tool. I created a yearly point density map using a shapefile of my country map and lightning data coordinates (latitudes, longitudes). Because each year has a varied density distribution across the country, I need help to plot the five-year data and obtain the yearly average density map.

Comment: And as I previously asked, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? We're a problem-solving site, using a Focused question/Best answer model. Right now you have a task, but not a problem. Without a picture of the data, all I can do is imagine you've started incorrectly, and that you need a uniform geometry basis to compare across years.

Comment: Thank you @Vince. I haven't tried any methods for calculating average density because I don't know what they are, which is the reason for asking the question here.